# mvc resource mapping strange mapping

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

i have strange problem with resource mapping.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/js/" />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/css/" />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/img/" />
```

And for mapping, for example jquery.js in view, i added:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/js/jquery.min.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and that's work, but when i added subdirectory, for example:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

that's return:  `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/xxx/resources/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`
and i have error 404 from Chrome elements.
What's wrong?

Comment: As far as I see error message indicates that resource mapping is working correctly. Make sure that such a file really exists. In particular, check character case in path.

Comment: file is exists, when I copy tiny_mce.js to parent directory (and change path to c:url value="/js/tiny_mce.js" />), in this case js directory, then it's work, but the problem is that tinyMCE has own subdirectory wich is reading when tiny_mce.js is executing and then the errors show again and relate to TinyMCE subdirectory.

Comment: Ok i resolve my problem, Clean and Build in Netbeans IDE refreshed all resources and after that it's work corectlly, stupid isn't it?